# Configuration File in Visual C# Database Sql Server Project

Tags: c#, sql-server, clr

Isit possible to use app.config file in Visual C# Database Sql Server Projects like any other winforms or webform projects.

Thanks in advance
Judes

Answer (score 1):

Not really, no.

You're effectively creating a class library project. Although you *can* add `app.config` files to such projects (normal ones, rather than SQL CLR ones), they're not actually usable at runtime (without jumping through a lot of hoops) - only the config file associated with the EXE project gets used.

Added to which, in this case, your code will actually be running inside the SQL Server process.